# What's this song in Highlander, season 6, episode 9?

Tags: music, music-identification, highlander

In the *Highlander* episode titled 'Deadly Exposure' there's a song that plays in the background during the outdoor photo shoot. In the below link it plays from around 6:55 to around 7:50. Can anybody identify this song?

Comment: The only thing listed in the soundtrack in IMDB  is Brahms' Hungarian Dance #5, and I don't thibk it's that. The photoshoot background  music just sounds like some random 90's techno piece.

Comment: The lyric is **"*there she never meant it*". something something "*She felt the strange desire to*" something something**. I've not found anything on google that matches the bits you can definitely make out, which suggests it was written specifically for the show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Where We Are Happy" by The Easter Island Philharmonic.  Google 'search a song' recognized it in a few seconds.